# Filtering out some lines of text using Scanner and PrintWriter

Tags: parsing, text, java.util.scanner, printwriter

I have ran into a very interesting phenomenon.  I have a text file which has its data organized in this way:

`2013-03-26T09:42:29 -1000 {"address": 6, "uptime_ms": 1354663, "bmp085_temp_decic": 307, "bmp085_press_pa": 101084, "batt_mv": 3284, "panel_mv": 4887, "apogee_mv": 247, "apogee_w_m2": 1235}`

There are about 10^6 lines inside this text.  Some of which, are garbage lines.  I wrote a code that would filter out the meaningful lines and write them into a separate text so that I can have a datafile with no garbage.  I distinguish if a line is 'useful' if it has a '{'. If it doesn't, then it skips that line.

Something peculiar happens though, my file stops reading the input text file about 45,000 lines in, and my newly written file never finishes.  I feel that it should return an error of some sort, but it doesn't and says my code has executed successfully.  My code looks like this:

```
   public void cleanFile() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    File file = new File("/home/foo/a/screenlog.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("/home/foo/a/scrlog.0");
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("{")) {
            pw.println(line);
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    pw.close();
}
```

Can someone please help me? I haven't a clue as to why.  As far as I can see, my code should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse the large text file using BufferedReader, InputStreamReader, and FileInputStream. So now my code works fine. As far as Scanner, I'm still guessing as to why this didn't work.  I know for sure that it lacks large file support, but can anyone point out why specifically BufferedReader works and why Scanner doesn't work?